# Unexpected value for window.innerWidth on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to get screen **width** and **height** on an Ionic 2 project.

To do so, I've created a new ionic 2 blank project and modified **home.html** and **home.ts** in order to store and display **innerWidth** and **innerHeight**.

*home.ts :*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  innerWidth: number;
  innerHeight: number;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
  }
}
```

*home.html :*

```
<ion-content padding>
  <p>innerWidth x innerHeight : {{ innerWidth }} x {{ innerHeight }}</p>
</ion-content>
```

When I serve the app on desktop, everything work as expected :
innerWidth x innerHeight : 1920 x 913

But when I run this app on Android , I get and unexpected value :
innerWidth x innerHeight : 360 x 574

This is quite strange because the resolution of my Android device is 1440 x 2560.

Any idea of what I might be missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the device pixel ratio. You have a device display with a very high ppi (pixels per inch), and probably a relatively smaller screen.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#A_pixel_is_not_a_pixel):

> For displays with density over 300dpi, the ratio is the integer floor(density/150dpi).

Based on the innerWidth and innerHeight values you get, your device's pixel ratio is 4, so 1440 x 2560 becomes 360 x 640. The reason you get a smaller than 640 innerHeight value is because of the bottom bar Android uses for its main navigation.

Comment: To find the pixel ratio, we can use window.devicePixelRatio

widthScreen = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio